# Titanium Appcelerator unable to run app on iphone device

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Unable to run on iphone device but it is okay on simulator

**Error Log**

```
[INFO] :   Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR] :  2016-12-09 12:02:48.529 xcodebuild[15867:179966]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-9061/Xcode3Core/LegacyProjects/Frameworks/DevToolsCore/DevToolsCore/Foundation/WorkQueues/XCWorkQueueCommandSubprocessInvocation.m:951
[ERROR] :  Details:  encountered read error on command output pipe (Bad file descriptor)
[ERROR] :  Object:   <XCWorkQueueCommandLocalSubprocessInvocation: 0x7fd4262434a0>
[ERROR] :  Method:   -handleOutputFileDescriptorActivity
[ERROR] :  Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd4271c3280>{number = 9, name = (null)}<br>
[ERROR] :  Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
**[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] : The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] : CompileStoryboard LaunchScreen.storyboard
[ERROR] :   CompileAssetCatalog build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Appname\ App3.app Assets.xcassets**
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
```

Use all latest, Xcode 8.1 and tisdk 6.0

Any one can help? thanks.

Comment: have you added the storyboard?

Comment: no it was just a fresh new project with only hello world.. but I already fixed it.  I already posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've researched and done some updates on this, but on my case I just created new provisioning profile and use it. I don't know why the log says about storyboard and assetscatalog, but  for me the error was fixed.